# Should a model that has a belongs_to relationship with 2 other models be nested under them in routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a web app for managing personal real estate . So I have the following models

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :name
  has_many :docs
end

class Land < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :name
  has_many :docs
end

class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Model for documents
  attr_accessible :name ,:actual_file
  has_attached_file :pdf
  belongs_to :building
  belongs_to :land
end
```

Now, What would be the best way to route this ? Should I nest docs separately in both building and land resource ? Or Is it better to not nest docs at all ? I know I could use polymorphic associations, but assume that I don't want to use them . Thsi question is more about the routing part.

This is my routes.rb

```
  resources :lands
  resources :buildings       
  resources :docs
```

What are the advantages of each approach ?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good case for [Routing Concerns](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns).

Although I am not sure this works in Rails 3 and without polymorphic relations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach...

```
  resources :lands do
    resources :docs
  end

  resources :buildings do
    resources :docs
  end
```

Then you can access docs like

```
/lands/:id/docs/:id
/buildings/:id/docs/:id
```

more readable also...

See more about nested routing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)